# Htaccess allow given ip to access only one url

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to figure out how to block an IP from accessing my website, other than one specific URL.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} = x.x.x.x [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/url/moreurl/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

Right now it seems like it is blocking everything.

EDIT:

```
# Set our application environment
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT beta

SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(somedomain.com|somedomain2.com)$" origin_is=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RedirectMatch 404 ^/symfony/?$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/system/?$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/db/?$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/application/?$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/vendor/?$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/queue_workers/?$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/crons/?$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/[^/]\.(yml|json|lock)$

# Allow IP to Specific URL (TESTING - works until adding ! to REQUEST_URI)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} ^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\s/url[NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# End of the line -- static files & directories, or otherwise pass into CI frontend controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule with `THE_REQUEST` as `REQUEST_URI` may change due to other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} = x.x.x.x
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/url/moreurl/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Or you can try: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php$|sellers)`